# do we have to add/remove a trailing slash for pagination page numbers in the url. how seo considers that?

Tags: seo, url-rewriting, pagination, google-panda-algorithm

My module is paginated. I want to either add a trailing slash or remove a trailing slash.
For now i am thinking of adding a trailing slashes to all URLS.

What will be the effect on adding a trailing slash for paginated URLS like `sitename.com/module/page/5/`

what will be the difference in `/page/5/` vs `/page/5` with respect to the users, seo and crawlers?

**The reason for always trailing slash on/off is to prevent duplicate content because of which the site gets penalized.**

Comment: In addition to the first answer below, you might also find the rel=next|prev interesting: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html as you mentioned pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. As long as you are consistent (by always using the slash or always omitting it), the URIs are just a string of text to search engines.